# Vector Property related problem

Tags: vectors

If $\overrightarrow b$ & $\overrightarrow c $ are two non-collinear unit vector and $\overrightarrow a $ is any vector then $\left( {\overrightarrow a .\overrightarrow b } \right)\overrightarrow b  + \left( {\overrightarrow a .\overrightarrow c } \right)\overrightarrow c  + \left( {\frac{{\overrightarrow a .\left( {\overrightarrow b  \times \overrightarrow c } \right)}}{{\left| {\overrightarrow b  \times \overrightarrow c } \right|}}} \right)\left( {\overrightarrow b  \times \overrightarrow c } \right) = \_\_\_\_\_\_$

I am not able to approach this problem.

Comment: If no rigorous method is needed take $a=i,b=j,c=k$ and find the value!

Comment: Then the answer is $\overrightarrow a $ which is the official answer but can it be solved via using property

Comment: Here is a hint: As $b,c,b\times c$ are not coplanar WLOG $$a=xc+yb+z(b\times c)$$Now can you find thye $x,y,z$? If stuck please show what you have tried along these lines